# How To Select Highest and Lowest Values from Another Table in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I have a table called `Tests` and a table `Points` and a number of other linked tables.

I am trying to select a summary of the Tests info which includes data from the other tables. Everything is working ok so far where there is only one column joined to a value in the `Tests` select query. So far, so good.

But, here is where I am struggling: for each test, there are a series of points recorded in the `Points` table and these are linked together by a typical foreign / primary (PK/FK) key arrangement to the `Test` record, and there are usually several hundred or even thousands of `Points` in each `Test`.

The `Points` are numbered sequentially from 1 to n for each `Test`, so the numbering for the `Points` for each new `Test` starts at 1 again.

In the `Tests` summary selection, I would like to see the value of `Points.Value_X` when `Points.Number = 1` and another column with the value of `Points.Value_X` when `Points.Number = n`

The idea is to retrieve just two values from the `Points` table into the tests summary, based on the points' order number of 1 and also on the maximum order number for that test.

`Points.Value_X` is a decimal number.

Please can someone help me with the query for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition aggregation, something like this:

```
select test_id,
       max(case when num = 1 then value_x end) as value_x_1,
       max(case when num = <n> then value_x end) as value_x_n
from points p
group by test_id;
```

The `<n>` value is assumed to be a constant when you run the query.

Comment: Ok, so I managed to make this work by looking at point No 1 and point No 10 in each data set.

But, I still need to JOIN this result into the main summary, and not able to make this work.